# Class which inherits fragment is considered incompatible in fragment adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I've been trying to use [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) from Google to develop functionality similar to google calendar dailyView using ViewPager. My Fragment java file is copied directly from the tutorial with the exception of my layout file having a different name.

```
public class DaySliderFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.single_day_content, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My Fragment adapter java file is also copied down from the tutorial as shown below

```
public class DaySliderFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

    public DaySliderFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new DaySliderFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

in the getItem method I'm getting an error saying DaySliderFragment is not a compatible type (fragment). Why would this be? I can't seem to find any discrepancies between my code and the code provided in the tutorial. Am I missing something?

Comment: show me `DaySliderFragment` 's import statements

Answer (score 1):

Upon some googling and carefully looking over my code I found the issue was actually in the import statements, not the code itself.

I needed to use

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

in DaySliderFragment.java